# Chrome extension native messaging host instantly disconnects

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make my chrome extension run a bash script through native messaging, but the host application just instantly disconnects. So if anyone can help me that'd be great, cause I've been trying to get this to work for several hours. It just instantly says disconnected when I get the message from my contentScript. I get no error message or anything and googles documentation for this is very bad. Thanks if you can help me.

this is my background.js

```
var port;

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
      file: 'contentScript.js'
    });
  })

});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    runScript();
  });

function runScript() {
  port = chrome.runtime.connectNative("crashFixingtonNative")
  port.onDisconnect.addListener(function() {
    console.log("Disconnected");
  });
}
```

this is my manifest.json(for the extension)

```
{
 "name" : "Crash Fixington",

 "version" : "1.0",

 "description" : "----",

 "permissions": ["tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "<all_urls>",
        "nativeMessaging"],

 "background" : {
    "scripts" : ["background.js"],
    "persistent" : true
 },

 "manifest_version": 2
}
```

my contentScript.js

```
(function() {
  var orderIdList = document.getElementsByClassName(" nowrap avoid-wrap");
  for (var i = 0; i < orderIdList.length; i++) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute('href', ''); // gives link standard look
    a.addEventListener("click", function() {
      requestRunScript();
      window.event.preventDefault();
    }, false);
    a.textContent = orderIdList[i].textContent;
    orderIdList[i].replaceWith(a);
  }

})();
function requestRunScript() {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
      greeting: ""
    },
    function(response) {});
}
```

and lastly my crashFixingtonNative.json(for my .sh script)

```
{
  "name": "crashFixingtonNative",
  "description": "crashFixingtonNative",
  "path": "/Library/Google/Chrome/NativeMessagingHosts",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://pfahbpdkjhgfjelhmbkedlcbbkpeiehk/"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Native messaging protocol requires your native app to implement a certain binary protocol described in the documentation. It's not just a bash piping.

Comment: Alright, I just want to run the script. I don't even need any return value. How do i just make it run my script ? I can't find any documentation on this binary protocol.

Comment: Documentation: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging

Comment: See also: [logging](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging).

Comment: the native messaging hasn't really helped me but loggin might. I'll look it up, thanks.